# I need help developing a form

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to create a form that will create a table of pricing for t-shirts.

There are 10 shirts to choose from and each one is a different price. The S through XL are the same price but the XXL is a different price.

Next there is a selection for the color of the garment which also varys the price and there are 3 options White, Athletic, and Color.

The 3rd selection is the number of colors in the print for the shirt. Which there are 5 options (1-2, 3-4, 5-6, 7-8, 9-10 which affects the price.

Then I also have a few checkboxes which are add-ons that add to the price also.

The final data I want to show is a 2 row table showing in each column the price for 48pc, 72pc, 96pc, 144pc, 288pc. The first row will be the price for S-XL and the 2nd row would be for the XXL price.

I've created a super huge file that does the calculations and comes up with a cost but I know there is a easier way and a correct way that what I did. How would you guys do a file like this and can anyone help me out? I'm about to go crazy I been working on it for the past week and half straight.

I didn't post it because it was to long. I uploaded it to gitHub though heres the link:
https://gist.github.com/1708558[GitHub](https://gist.github.com/1708558)

Comment: Please post what code you have tried thus far. It will really help in giving you a relevant answer.

Comment: What adam is trying to say is that your post would garner much more interest and responses if you formatted your text in to paragraphs and posted some code samples.

Comment: Sorry about my paragraph formatting... I been working for about 15 hours but thats still no excuse. I put a link to my code in the original post.

Comment: Let me introduce you to the `switch` statement: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/switch.shtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, there is an easier way - you can write a php script that will generate all this code automatically!

For example, you create in your MySQL DB a table that will hold the < key,val > of all the shirts:

< DT0001 , DT0001SHIRTCOLOR >
< DT000161 , DT000161SHIRTCOLOR >
...

and then you read the data from your PHP script and print/echo, for example:

```
echo "$(document).ready(function(){ $(\"#garmentselect\").change(function(){ ";

$con = mysql_connect("db-machine","username","password")
               or die("Unable to connect to SQL server");
mysql_select_db("schema") or die("Unable to select database");
$query = "select key,value from my_shirts;";
$result =  mysql_query($query) or die("No Records Found!");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

    echo "if ($(this).val() == '".$row[key]."' ) { $('#".$row[val]."').slideDown("fast"); } else { $('#".$row[val].").slideUp("fast");}";
}
mysql_close($con);
echo "});"; // end of $("#garmentselect").change(...";
//continue ...
```

You can do this with most of your code and avoid duplication. In general, whenever you copy & paste your code and change only the parameters - you should think about creating a generalized method that will get the parameters as input and will generate the code you wanted to copy (this principle is called "code re-use").

Hope I helped.